# OpenSuse switches GPUs mid-setup

Tags: opensuse, nvidia, gpu, optimus

While installing OpenSuse Tumbleweed on an Optimus-equipped laptop, I have the problem that mid-setup (without a fixed time) the setup switches from the external GPU (which is used while booting) to the internal GPU, thus freezing the whole setup. Is there a way to prevent that? Otherwise I can not install the OS.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities -> texmode installation or specify BrokenModules.

Both are possible to specify in Boot options line of Bootloader screen.

- texmode is specifieed by `texmode=1`
- BrokenModules - `BrokenModules=i915` -- this prevents intel gpu driver from loading.

More information about linuxrc in openSUSE : https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Linuxrc#Parameter_Reference